# Wiman-Valiron theory

Tags: complex-analysis

In Wiman-Valiron theory we have the comparison method which compares an etire function with a fully indexed power series to get estmates for the terms of entire function. In the case of functions that are analytic in the unit disc there is proved the same results but using a non-increasing function \psi on (0,1) to obtain the estimates.

My question is, why they use the funtion \psi in order to get the estimates for function analytic in the unit disc?